# Help with Shell Model and Pauli Exclusion Principle

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, protons, pauli-exclusion-principle

As I understand, the occupancy number in the nuclear shell model dictates the number of each type of nucleon that can occupy a specific sub-shell (angular momentum state l).

Note: s, p, d, f corresponds to l=0, l=1, l=2,... respectively.

My current understanding is that it works like this. The n=1 shell can be occupied by only the l=0 (s) angular momentum state, while the n=2 shell can be occupied by the l=0 and l=1 (p) angular momentum states and so on.

The occupancy number for the number of each type of nucleon is $$N=(2l+1)$$

Using this, I am having trouble making sense of the image below from my lecture course on subatomic physics. What do the subscripts of 1/2 and 3/2 refer to? Also, according to my understanding there should be no 1p sub shell as only the s angular momentum state is allowed in the n=1 shell.

If anyone could explain this diagram to me and clear up any misconceptions I have about the shell model, I would greatly appreciate it.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nuclear shell (per nucleon) model differs from the atomic shell model because of spin-orbit coupling and parity.

Because the orbiting particles are identical, the even shells (starting from $0$) can only have even $l$, and the odd shells can only have odd $l$. Thus:
the 1st shell is $l=0$, the 2nd is $l=1$, the 3rd is $l=(0,2)$ and so on.
With that, the traditional atomic physics $n$ is not used, and shells are counted as follows: $1S$ is the 1st $l=0$ shell, and $2S$ is the second one, and do on. Hence $1D$ and $2S$ are part of the same group. They all start at $1$, and continue from there.

Regarding the fractional subscript: the nuclear force is strong, so spin-orbit coupling doesn't fall under "fine structure", it's just structure. With that, the nucleon spin quantum numbers $m_s$ aren't good quantum numbers, but the total $\vec J=\vec L + \vec S$  projections on the $z$-axis are. Hence: the subscript is $j$.

The 1st shell is $1S_{\frac 1 2}$, where $m_j = \frac 1 /2$ is a trivial combination of $l=0$ and $s=\frac 1 2$.

In atomic physics, the $2P$ shell has three $m_l=(-1, 0, 1)$ times two $m_s = \pm \frac 1 2$ states. In the nucleus that becomes the four $j=\frac 3 2$ plus two $j=\frac 1 2$ states. And again, because it's the 1st available $P$ shell, it is labeled $1P_{j}$.